# C++ programming struct vector with multiple arguments and params as member

Tags: c++

Trying to create a struct that has a vector as a member, but unable to make it work if vector has multiple args.

Any ideas?

```
struct node {
    int         id;
    std::string name;
    bool        visited;
    int         state;
    std::vector <std::string, int> edges;
};
```

I'd like the vector to be of this type; std::vector <std::string, int>  string and int.

This is the error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:477:20: error: '_M_get_Tp_allocator' has not been declared in 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::_Base'
  477 |       using _Base::_M_get_Tp_allocator;
```

Comment: `std::vector <std::pair<std::string, int>> edges;`

Comment: `std::vector` only holds one type. Nothing to do with `struct`. If you don't need to preserve the insertion order and perform lookups using the string as a key a `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` might be a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) holds a sequence of a single type.

e.g. `std::vector<int> v_int` holds a sequence of *only* integers.

There are types that can themselves hold multiple types. For example, a [`std::pair<std::string, int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) holds both a `string` and an `int`.

It is possible to have a vector of pairs, if that is what you are trying to do.

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> edges;
```

Comment: Thank to all for the help and support. I just started to re-learned C++ and many of the new features are very interesting. It just seemed odd that I could not declare a vector of/such ```std::vector <std::string, int> edges;```

Comment: any way, I have modified the code to something more flexible.

Comment: ```struct edge {
 int   id;
    std::string name;
 int   distance;
};

struct node {
 int   id;
    std::string name;
 int   state;
    int   status;
 std::vector<struct edge> edges;
};

struct graph {
 int  id;
 std::vector<struct node> nodes;
};```